# Did Gohan ask Piccolo to do fusion?

Tags: japanese-language, dragon-ball-super

In *Dragon Ball Super* episode 88, around 20:15 mark, Gohan said something to Piccolo about the idea to become more powerful.

In one subtitle, I've read Gohan asked Piccolo to do some attack or technique together. But in other translation, Gohan asked Piccolo to do a combined technique or a ***fusion*** together.

It's also raising speculation among fans too ([YouTube video about Gohan's fusion with Piccolo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0TvIKITZevA))

Which one is true?

Comment: Was the translation official?  That is, was it done by a licensed distributor and not a fansub?

Comment: fansub, meaning it could be inaccurate, but it could be accurate too. Since I've seen another one which doesnt say exactly the same, I would bet it's inaccurate, but it comes from a very popular anime webpage.

Comment: I would never place any faith in any translation that a fansub has.  Nothing's official until the anime actually has an official translation.

Comment: Anyway, any japanese can give a real answer to this. No need to wait for an official translation

Comment: I understand half ot the question. A part says if they dont want to do a combination attack or technique together. And the first half it's the one which talks about doing another thing together, but I can't understand what

Comment: In another subtitled version says "why dont we create a double team maneuver or a combination together". My bet is the first subtitles extrapolated "combination" to "fusion" , when Gohan originally meant combination attack and not fusion, but not sure

Comment: @AkiTanaka please, post your comment as answer so I can vote it up and approve it.

Comment: it's raising speculations among fans too https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0TvIKITZevA

Comment: After researching some more, seems I was wrong. I've posted an answer which should be (more) correct. Meanwhile, you may clean-up some of your comments by removing them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gohan said

> あっ、だったら、合体技とか、コンビネーションとか、作りませんか？

which can be translated to

> Oh, then why don't we create a [double-team](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/double-team) maneuvers or a combination?
>
> <sup>(From unknown English fansub)</sup>

In general, 合体技 (*gattai waza*) means "combination technique by two or more people". **Fusion** is one of them, and is probably the source of confusion since in Japanese, ○○と合体する (*○○ to gattai suru*) means "to fuse with someone" (example: [Gotenks](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Gotenks)). However, it doesn't mean specifically "fusion". Other examples are [Purple Comet Crush](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Purple_Comet_Attack) and [Purple Comet Hurricane](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Purple_Comet_Hurricane) by Burter and Jeice.

Combination attack, according to [Wikia](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_techniques), means "*techniques which combine the different basic-types to continuously attack an opponent to leave no room for counterattacks*". Example is [Kibito Kai](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Kibito_Kai)'s [Crazy Combination](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Crazy_Combination).