# Piccolo-Gohan fusion, can it be allowed in the Universal Tournament?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-super

In Dragon Ball Super episode 88th, according to some subtitles in a popular anime webpage, confirmed by Anime SE member Aki Tanaka who speaks japanese, Gohan literally says to Piccolo "If so, should we create a fusion technique, or combination (attack)?" .

[what does the original japanese audio says in episode 88th when Gohan is talking to Piccolo and asks him to do something in the battle together?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/40115/what-does-the-original-japanese-audio-says-in-episode-88th-when-gohan-is-talking)

According to what's been said up to today about the Universal Tournament rules, could this be allowed?

Comment: To be clear: the statement was from my comment which I have deleted since I was wrong (and posted the correct one as an answer). Probably you should delete this, or change the question if you could.

Comment: Well, the Fusion dance is a technique that the characters can perform without external assistance or tools, so in this sense it *should* be allowed...

The problem is that this technique would "create" an eleventh fighter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the introduction of Kefla, Fusion is definitely allowed, even with Potarra earrings.

Techniques which causes fusion are definitely allowed, as seen in the example of Aniraza.